# Interpretating Issue: 2 Main Variables Significant, Interaction Variable insignificant

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, interpretation

I just want to make sure that I have not misunderstood the interpretation of having two statistically significant main variables and one insignficant interaction variable.

My multiple Regression analyses the impact of Investment Funding (first explanatory variable) on the Stock Return of Banks. In addition I added a dummy variable Financial Advisor (1 = yes, 0 = no) which indicates my second explanatory variable. I found out that a Investment Funding as well as the Financial Advisor have a statistically significant effect (Investment Funding Coef. is positive; Financial Advisor is negative). My interaction variable (Investment Funding*Financial Advisor) is insignificant with a negative Coef.

Interpretation:
The Investment Funding Coef. implies that stock returns of companies are higher in periods with increasing Investment funding. While stock returns are lower for companies with an Financial Advisor.
The interaction variable indicates, that there is no relationship between those two variable as the interaction term is insignificant. This means that the effect of Investment Funding on stock return does not depend on having a Financial Advisor?

Have I understood this right or not?

My hypothesis for the interaction variable was actually, that Investment Funding positively amplifies stock returns of companies with a Financial Advisor(This Hypothesis was conducted before running the regression, based on some Literature).

Comment: Does anybody has an idea? or is my question very confusing?

Comment: Anyone? :)

I can further explain if needed